# How to remove spacebar action from QToolButton

Tags: qt

I have a QToolBar on which there is a QToolButton. When QToolButton is pressed by mouse click then it perform some action. The same action is performed when space bar is pressed. I dont want the action to be fired on space bar press, but I want it on mouse click. How I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subclass QToolButton using inheritance and override `QWidget::keyPressEvent()`. There, check if the key you get is `Qt::Key_Space` and if it is, return and do nothing. if it isn't pass the event to QToolButton.

Answer (score 4):

Use the set focus policy with no focus, this prevents the keyboard from having focus but still allows mouse clicks.

```
Button->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you didn't accidentally assign 'Space' as the shortcut to the action associated with the QToolButton in question (check out Qt Creater's action editor).